# How can I skip multiple for loop iterations in R like Python?

Tags: r, loops, iterator

As you can see in python code below if condition is satisfied, iteration skips 1, 5, and 9.

```
range_iter = iter(range(10))

for i in range_iter:
    print(i)
    if i % 4 == 0:
        next(range_iter)
        print('Condition satisfied',i)
```

```
0
Condition satisfied 0
2
3
4
Condition satisfied 4
6
7
8
Condition satisfied 8
```

I tried this. But it was no use.

```
library(iterators)

range_iter <- iterators::iter(0:9)

for (i in range_iter) {
  if (i %% 4 == 0) {
    next(range_iter) 
    print(paste("Condition satisfied",i))
  }
}
```

I get en error:`Error in i%%4 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

How can I do this in R ?

Comment: With the same command: `next`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R doesn't have any command to skip the next iteration.  The `next` statement (alone, not a function call like `next(range_iter)`) will skip the current one.

So to do what you want you'd write the loop like this:

```r
skip <- FALSE
for (i in 0:9) {
  if (skip) {
    skip <- FALSE
    next
  }
  print(i)
  if (i %% 4 == 0) {
    skip <- TRUE 
    print(paste("Condition satisfied",i))
  } 
}
#> [1] 0
#> [1] "Condition satisfied 0"
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 4
#> [1] "Condition satisfied 4"
#> [1] 6
#> [1] 7
#> [1] 8
#> [1] "Condition satisfied 8"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have yet another question. What if I want to skip more than one iteration, what I should do then ?

Comment: I think for a complicated situation like that a `for` loop is inappropriate.  You could put all indices into a vector, and remove them as handled or when you see they should be skipped, then run the whole thing as `while(length(indices) > 0) { i <- indices[1], .... }`.

Comment: Or maybe keep a vector of future skips instead of just one as in my answer.  The test becomes `if (i %in% skips) next`.  That would still work with the `for` loop.

Comment: This is a poor way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are, in general, much better off creating your desired indices a priori,

such as

```
idx <-  seq(0,10) %% 4
idx <-  idx[idx > 0] 

for (jdx in idx) { do_stuff}
```

Or of course if you only wanted the zero values,

```
idx <- seq(0,10) %% 4 
idx <- which(idx == 0 )
```